# enable bootstrap nav button at different screen size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

i'm trying to enable the toggle button on responsive devices but minimum at 900px,
the default size is 768px.
The code that i'm trying to customize is the same as bootstrap example.

thanks for any help!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Use the media queries in CSS - not HTML - to enable the button at a larger screen size.

Comment: You could make a custom Bootstrap CSS with a larger break point, or do as Brian suggests and override the default CSS with a larger media query.

Comment: hi guys, thanks in advance! i tried with media queries something like this:

@media (max-width: 900px){

 .navbar-collapse.collapse {
   display: none!important;
   height: auto!important;
   padding-bottom: 0;
   overflow: visible!important;
 }
 .navbar-toggle{
  display: block;
 }

}
but the result wasn't that i wanted!

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
@media(max-width: 900px) {
    .dropdown-toggle {
         display: inline-block;
     }
}
```

hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I'm getting ur question correctly but, If u want to hide the nav button only on the large screen then use this:

```
  <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#Navbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
```

navbar-expand-[lg], lg will make it expand in large screen, and other screens the button appeared.